# Adding Form tag to html elements created by innerHTML

Tags: php, javascript, html

I am dynamically creating html elements: a **text box** and a **submit button** which on submitting should go to a php code and place the data in a database.

But the php part is not working if anyone can tell where I'm going wrong

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>My first PHP page</title>
<script>
    function addsubdomain()
    {
        document.getElementById('subdomain').innerHTML  +="<form id='form1' method='post' action='new.php'> \n\
            <input type='text' id='textid' name='subdomain' value='' /><br /> \n\
            <input type='button' id='button2' name='submit2' value='submit'/></form>";
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>       
    <input type="button" id="button1 "name="submit1"  value="Add SubDomain" onclick="addsubdomain();"/>
    <div id="subdomain"></div>
     <?php
        if(isset($_POST['submit2']))
        {
            echo "hii";// Not working not coming here
            echo $_POST['subdomain'];
        // Insert Query
        }                      
     ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: put this at the top of your code <? echo "<pre>"; print_r($_POST); ?> to show what is getting posted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently in your javascript your dynamic button type is button hence it is not submitting the form. Hence, Change your type='button' to type='submit' in javascript. i.e change it like this

```
document.getElementById('subdomain').innerHTML  +="<form id='form1' method='post' action='new.php'> <input type='text' id='textid' name='subdomain' value='' /><br /> <input type='submit' id='button2' name='submit2' value='submit'/></form>";
```

Comment: Yeah It works on changing type from 'button' to 'submit' Thanks Chandresh
I'll be careful not to make this error again :)

Comment: One more thing how to get the value entered in the text box?
echo $_POST['subdomain']; is not printing the value

Comment: It should basically if your abc.php is correct file then it should do it.

Comment: Yeah again you're right I messed up with file names :| Thanks